# How can I change the way R plots dates in a time series graph?

Tags: r

```
forecast = forecast.Arima(model,h=4)
upper = ts(forecast$upper[,2], start=c(2016,12), frequency = 12)
lower = ts(forecast$lower[,2], start=c(2016,12), frequency = 12)
forecasted = forecast$mean
plot(cbind(window(manu, start=c(2015,12), end=c(2017,03), frequency=12), 
upper, lower, forecasted), plot.type="single", 
col=c("red","black","black","green"))
```

Here's the code I'm using right now, and instead of saying April 2016, it says 2016.4. I tried to strip the axis using the commands I found, but it seems to be resistant to allowing it. Any ideas?

Comment: The first line falls apart on my machine.  What is `forecast.Arima`?

Comment: Did you try axis.Date()?